# How to automatically insert braces after starting a code block in vim?

Tags: vim

It's really easy to insert a closing brace after typing the opening one:

```
inoremap { {<CR>}<Esc>ko
```

This way

`if (true) {`

converts to

```
if (true) {
    |
}
```

But I'd like to save time and to type 1 character less:

`if (true)<CR>`

So I'd like to create the following rule: if return is pressed and the line starts with if/for/while, execute `{<CR>}<Esc>ko`

Is this doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on your previous mapping, this should do what you want:

```
inoremap )<CR> ) {<CR>}<Esc>ko
```

However, you should try a snippet expansion plugin like SnipMate or Ultisnips. Both plugins allow you to define snippets with placeholders and miroring (lots of them are included by default) that are expanded when a `<Tab>` is pressed after a trigger.

For example, you have a snippet associated with the trigger `if` that expands into:

```
if ([condition]) {

}
```

`condition` is selected, ready for you to type, and, once you are done, you can hit `<Tab>` again to jump the cursor between the curly braces, ready to type:

```
if (myVar == 5) {
  |
}
```

This is incredibly handy.

Comment: +1 right way to go. if you map ) or `<cr>`, even `)<cr>` you have to check (`expr`) if it is following `if, switch, for.....` otherwise your handy mapping would be annoying sometimes. I recommend snipmate too.

Comment: Mappings like this one are "dumb", they may work on the surface… until you find a tricky corner case. If one wants a solid solution, scripting quickly becomes necessary.